# ElasticSearch - cannot run two es docker containers at the same time

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

## ElasticSearch - cannot run two es docker containers at the same time

I'm trying to run 2 services of `ElasticSearch` using `docker-compose.yaml`

Every time I run `docker-compose up -d` only one service is working at time. When I try to start stopped service it runs but the first one which was working before, stops immediately.

This is how my `docker-compose.yaml` looks like:

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services:
  es-write:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
    container_name: es-write
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - TAKE_FILE_OWNERSHIP=true
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  es-read:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
    container_name: es-read
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - TAKE_FILE_OWNERSHIP=true
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9201:9200
  sqs:
    image: "roribio16/alpine-sqs:latest"
    container_name: "sqs"
    ports:
      - "9324:9324"
      - "9325:9325"
    volumes:
      - "./.docker-configuration:/opt/custom"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Tldr;

I believe you get the known `<container name> exited with code 137` error.

Which is docker way of telling you it is OOM (out of memory).

## To solve

Define a maximum amount of Ram each container is allowed to use.
I allowed `4GB`, but you choose what suits you.

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services:
  es-write:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
    container_name: es-write
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4GB  # Use at most 50 MB of RAM
  es-read:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.0
    container_name: es-read
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9201:9200
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4GB  # Use at most 50 MB of RAM
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo for your answer, works as expected!

Comment: That's great to hear